# node, unexpected JSON response

Tags: json, node.js, rest

I'm very new to programming. So if my question is not clear enough please just tell me, and I'will try to make it simpler. Any way, I make a request from some Restful API,
[with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4pQe.png)

```
const request = require('request');

var myJSONObject = {
"call":"ListarContasReceber",
"app_key":"1560731700",
"app_secret":"226dcf372489bb45ceede61bfd98f0f1",
"param":
  [
    {
      "pagina":1,
      "registros_por_pagina":1,
      "apenas_importado_api":"N"
    }
  ]
};

request({
    url: "http://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/contareceber/",
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    body: myJSONObject
}, function (error, response, body){
    console.log(response.body.info.cImpAPI == 'S');
});
```

and it should return some thing like this:

```
{
  "pagina": 1,
  "total_de_paginas": 252,
  "registros": 1,
  "total_de_registros": 252,
  "conta_receber_cadastro": [
    {
      "bloqueado": "N",
      "bloquear_baixa": "N",
      "boleto": {
        "cGerado": "",
        "cNumBancario": "",
        "cNumBoleto": "",
        "dDtEmBol": "",
        "nPerJuros": 0,
        "nPerMulta": 0
      }, ...
```

But instead I get this:

```
{ pagina: 1,
  total_de_paginas: 252,
  registros: 1,
  total_de_registros: 252,
  conta_receber_cadastro: 
   [ { bloqueado: 'N',
       bloquear_baixa: 'N',
       boleto: [Object], ...
```

See? this boleto attribute should be another object, but I can't access it.

Does anybody knows what did i'm wrong?

Comment: We can't tell you what you did wrong if you haven't told us what you've done.

Comment: My comment still stands, that's just a console output. it doesn't indicate anything that you've done other than sending it to the console. Looks fine thus far and should be accessible.

Comment: if u are seeing this after `console.log(response)`, try to use `console.log(JSON.parse(response))`

Comment: hi Kevin, thanks for help, i'm just could not indent correctly, so a take a screen shot, If you can Look, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Yeah, it all looks fine thus far. You should have no problem accessing that property.

Comment: I tried use the JSON.parse(), but just return me a syntax error like this, SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. probably because the content of the response.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **We can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: tanks for the tip tadman, i think is better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wasn't access the key conta_receber_cadastro :D

```
request({
    url: "http://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/contareceber/",
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    body: myJSONObject
}, function (error, response, body){
    console.log(body.conta_receber_cadastro);
});
```